# Trying to find a clicked div's value, returns empty instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty sure the solution is staring at me in the face, but I can't see it!

This is what I want to achieve:

When a div is clicked, find the clicked div's value (not text), and console log it out.
But when I do that, it returns an empty value instead.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div id="d4" class="dice" value="4">?</div>
<div id="d6" class="dice" value="6">?</div>
<div id="d8" class="dice" value="8">?</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.dice').click(function() {
  var currentDice = $(this).val();
  console.log(currentDice);
 });
});
```

Comment: `$(el).val()` reads the value for an `input`/`textarea`/`select`, not a div.

Comment: Wow, all this time I thought .val() was just to find its value="". I feel like an idiot now. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "attr"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dice').click(function() {
  var currentDice = $(this).attr("value");
    console.log(currentDice);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is used for form elements (input, select, etc), that actually have a true name value pair associated. Because you are using a div, you should be getting the attribute of value (`.attr('value')`):

That being said, and while that works, you really should use the `data-` attribute for custom attributes on elements (ex: `data-value="4"`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dice').click(function() {
    var currentDice = $(this).attr('data-value');
    console.log(currentDice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d4" class="dice" data-value="4">?</div>
<div id="d6" class="dice" data-value="6">?</div>
<div id="d8" class="dice" data-value="8">?</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
$('.dice').click(function() {
  var currentDice = $(this).attr('value');
  console.log(currentDice);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` is not a valid attribute for `<div>` elements (please see [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)). Don't clutter up the DOM with invalid attributes, use `data-` instead:

```
<div id="d4" class="dice" data-value="4">?</div>
<div id="d6" class="dice" data-value="6">?</div>
<div id="d8" class="dice" data-value="8">?</div>
```

jQuery's `val()` function is not a drop-in for `attr()` or similar. If you update your markup to use `data-` attributes, you can then use jQuery's [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dice').click(function() {
        var currentDice = $(this).data('value');
        console.log(currentDice);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` isn't a `div` attribute so I suggest the use of `data-*` attributes instead when you want to add costum attribute, like :

```
<div id="d4" class="dice" data-value="4">?</div>
```

Then in your js use the jQuery method `.data()` :

```
$(this).data('value');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dice').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('value'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d4" class="dice" data-value="4">?</div>
<div id="d6" class="dice" data-value="6">?</div>
<div id="d8" class="dice" data-value="8">?</div>
```